# `Or` between `.Where` using Linq or Entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a function that Search from `Words` table using linq. I want to `.split(' ')` input words and search each of them. But I want `or` between my conditions not `and`. See Generated SQL Code.

```
public static List<Word> GetWords(string word_Fa, string word_En)
{
    var db = Global.GetEntitiy();

    var query = from item in db.Words
                select item;

    foreach (var item in word_Fa.Split(' '))
    {
        query = query.Where(a => a.Word_Fa.Contains(item));
    }

    foreach (var item in word_En.Split(' '))
    {
        query = query.Where(a => a.Word_En.Contains(item));
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Generated SQL code:

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[UserID], [t0].[Word_En], [t0].[Word_Fa], [t0].[UpVotes], [t0].[DownVotes], [t0].[DateTime], [t0].[Status]
FROM [Words] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Word_En] LIKE @p0) AND ([t0].[Word_En] LIKE @p1) AND ([t0].[Word_Fa] LIKE @p2) AND ([t0].[Word_Fa] LIKE @p3)
```

Comment: sorry I correct it..

Comment: do you want 'or' between conditions in each foreach?

Comment: no for all conditions... for all foreachs..

Comment: have a look on this link please http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx , and be careful when using Or because ( A and B or C ) different from A and (B or C), hope this will help you

Comment: @HadiHassan it works when using Linq, but I'am using entity framework. it gives me error: `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might consider using predicate builder from [Here](http://albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) as @Hadi Hassan said in the comments .
and by using that , your codes would be like this :

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Words>();

var query = from item in Words
            select item;

var FaWords = "A B C".Split(' ');
var EnWords = "D E F".Split(' ');

foreach (string item in FaWords)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Word_Fa.Contains(item));
}

foreach (string item in EnWords)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Word_En.Contains(item));
}

return query.Where(predicate).toList();
```

and the sql query would be :

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[UserID], [t0].[Word_En], [t0].[Word_Fa], [t0].[UpVotes], [t0].
[DownVotes], [t0].[DateTime], [t0].[Status]
FROM [Words] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Word_Fa] LIKE @p0) OR ([t0].[Word_Fa] LIKE @p1) OR ([t0].[Word_Fa] LIKE @p2) OR ([t0].[Word_En] LIKE @p3) OR ([t0].[Word_En] LIKE @p4) OR ([t0].[Word_En] LIKE @p5)
```

by the way , if you got this error : The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

you should add the [LinqKit](http://nuget.org/packages/LinqKit) nuget package to your project and change the return line to :

```
return query.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).toList();
```

good luck

Answer (score 2):

Solution without using LinqKit:

Extension Class very similar to PredicateBuilder, but it works with linq to entities and linq to sql out of the box:

```
public static class PredicateHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        if (expr1 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expr1");
        }
        if (expr2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expr2");
        }
        var visitor = new ParameterUpdateVisitor(expr2.Parameters.First(), expr1.Parameters.First());
        expr2 = visitor.Visit(expr2) as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        if (expr1==null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expr1");
        }
        if (expr2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expr2");
        }
        var visitor = new ParameterUpdateVisitor(expr2.Parameters.First(), expr1.Parameters.First());
        expr2 = visitor.Visit(expr2) as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    class ParameterUpdateVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _oldParameter;
        private readonly ParameterExpression _newParameter;

        public ParameterUpdateVisitor(ParameterExpression oldParameter, ParameterExpression newParameter)
        {
            _oldParameter = oldParameter;
            _newParameter = newParameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(node, _oldParameter))
                return _newParameter;

            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

use absolutely equal to PredicateBuilder:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Words>();

var query = from item in Words
            select item;

var FaWords = "A B C".Split(' ');
var EnWords = "D E F".Split(' ');

foreach (string item in FaWords)
{
    var item1 = item;
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Word_Fa.Contains(item1));
}

foreach (string item in EnWords)
{
    var item1 = item;
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Word_En.Contains(item1));
}

return query.Where(predicate).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I think this should work for you:

```
public static List<Word> GetWords(string word_Fa, string word_En)
{
    var db = Global.GetEntitiy();
    return db.Words
                .Where(w => w.Word_Fa.Intersect(word_Fa.Split(' ')).Any() ||
                            w.Word_En.Intersect(word_En.Split(' ')).Any())
                .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to check `word_Fa` in every item in `query` with every item in `word_Fa.Split(' ')`. So join them on that string and it will give you all the items in `query` which are also in `word_Fa.Split(' ')`:

```
var query1 = (from q in query
    join item in word_Fa.Split(' ') on q.Word_Fa equals item
    select q).ToList();

var query2 = (from q in query
    join item in word_En.Split(' ') on q.Word_En equals item
    select q).ToList();

return query1.Union(query2);
```

Comment: IT IS OBVIOUS!! 

You want to check `word_Fa` in every item in `query` with every item in `word_Fa.Split(' ')`. So `join` them on that string and it will give you all the items in `query` which are also in `word_Fa.Split(' ')`. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Raeen query was helpful because he combined all loops you made in one query using Linq, but it needs to add another line for word_En and it will be perfect

Comment: note that Split in order to work you need to add AsEnumerable in first line: var query=db.Words.AsEnumerable(); because there is not translation for Split function to Sql, then use @RaeenHashemi solution and it will work, or use the Predicate Builder idea and your problem will be solved, hope this will help you

Comment: @HadiHassan Thanks for your attention, I've made the edit. Please check